# Are Muslim women allowed to marry revert Muslims?

Tags: nikah, women, conversion

In Islam the men are allowed to marry non-Muslims whereas the women are not allowed to marry non-Muslims. However, Muslim men are only allowed to marry a non-Muslim if she reverts to Islam. Does this mean that women are not allowed to marry reverts then? I am confused because even when the man is marrying the non-Muslim, they have to marry them on the basis they will revert otherwise the marriage is invalid. Or does this mean men are allowed to marry the non-Muslim women who are people of the book even before they revert but women are only allowed to marry the men who are people of the book after they revert to Islam?

Comment: A converted Muslim is to be treated as any other normal Muslim, unless / until he leaves Islam.

Comment: Muslim women can marry Muslim men (which reverts are), and non-Muslims (ie. Jews & christians) do not have to intend to become Muslim to be marry-able, that is just not a condition. They may remain their whole lives as Christians or Jews, and the marriage will remain legal.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question in the title, yes, Muslim Women **are allowed** to marry reverts. It happens in our community in Michigan a lot. Now, regarding your confusion:

> "I am confused because even when the man is marrying the non-Muslim,
>   they have to marry them on the basis they will revert otherwise the
>   marriage is invalid"

This is debatable. Some scholars have said that Muslim men can marry from the people of the book if they, non-Muslim women, are not practicing any sort of Shirk (Association partners with Allah), and they don't have to promise to revert to Islam later.

Comment: It seems as an brief admirable response. God bless you.

Answer (score -5):

All muslim women can Marry non muslim men. There is no need to revert. Just keep your faith on your god. There is no any boundation for marriage its your choice whome to marry. You all women are free to marry non muslim men.

Comment: Claims should be supported with evidence. The questioner is asking for the Islamic law on the matter and not your opinion.

Comment: Correction. Muslim women cannot marry a non Muslim, God has forbidden this marriage.